# touchstart Event do not work using Animate CC JavaScript in IPAD

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, animate-cc

Events like touchstart,touchend does not work in Actual IPad and in chrome Simulation in Animate CC JavaScript

```
element.addEventListener("touchstart", function f2_MouseClickHandler(e) {
                correctAnswer(e, position, responseId);
}.bind(self));
```

Comment: `.on` is jquery function to bind event handler. Otherwise, you're supposed to use `ontouchstart` with pure js. Just to make sure if you've included your jquery as well..

Comment: @choz I changed my question I am using pure JS

Answer (score 1):

I found Solution I forgot to enable touch on stage

createjs.Touch.enable(stage);

I Hope it help someone else 
Source:https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2177196